# unsafe map file /etc/mail/access.db: Permission denied

Tags: email, sendmail, dkim

when sending mail through Sendmail an error is displayed:

**vectortrade sm-mta[16951]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): hash map "access": unsafe map file /etc/mail/access.db: Permission denied**

what rights should be?
Now we set the following:

```
root@a:/etc/mail# ls -la
total 232
drw---S---  7 smmta smmsp  4096 Mar 22 06:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 89 root  root   4096 Mar 22 09:11 ..
-rw-------  1 root  root   4261 Mar 22 03:16 access
-rwx-wx--x  1 root  root  12288 Mar 22 03:16 access.db
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root    281 Feb 11  2014 address.resolve
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  smmsp    10 Feb  7 04:30 aliases -> ../aliases
-rw-r-----  1 root  smmsp 12288 Mar 22 03:16 aliases.db
-rw-r--r--  1 root  smmsp  3218 Mar 22 05:25 databases
-rw-------  1 root  root    826 Mar 22 06:04 dkim.key
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root   5657 Feb 11  2014 helpfile
-rw-r--r--  1 root  smmsp    47 Mar 22 04:12 local-host-names
drwxr-sr-x  2 smmta smmsp  4096 Feb  7 04:30 m4
-rwxr-xr--  1 root  smmsp  9994 Mar 22 05:25 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root   4096 Feb  7 04:30 peers
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  smmsp  4096 Feb 11  2014 sasl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  smmsp 60131 Mar 22 05:25 sendmail.cf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  12236 Mar 22 03:16 sendmail.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  smmsp  4218 Mar 22 05:23 sendmail.mc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root    149 Feb 11  2014 service.switch
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root    180 Feb 11  2014 ervice.switch-nodns
drwxr-sr-x  2 smmta smmsp  4096 Feb  7 04:30 smrsh
-rw-r--r--  1 root  smmsp 44049 Mar 22 03:16 submit.cf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  smmsp  2383 Mar 22 03:16 submit.mc
drwxr-xr-x  2 smmta smmsp  4096 Feb  7 04:30 tls
-rw-r--r--  1 root  smmsp     0 Feb  7 04:30 trusted-users
```

Help me to understand. It happened after a set DKIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are facing is:

> hash map "access": unsafe map file /etc/mail/access.db

means that `sendmail` identify potential security issue with the permission access to the file/folder. i.e. non-root user might be able to use it in order to gain `root` permission.

**Limiting access to the file/folder to root only:**

- The file `access.db` is writeable to both user `root` and group `root`.

The following will allow writing to this file only by `root` and not by group `root` and will make this file safer (as only `root` account will be able to write to this file)

```
sudo chmod g-w /etc/mail/access.db
```

- according to [this old book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sendmail-4th-edition/9780596510299/ch04s05s04.html)  `/etc/mail` directory should be owner by root.

In your case, the directory is owner by non root user.

Updating `/etc/mail` permissions to be owned by root:

```
sudo chown root /etc/mail
```

Updating `/etc/mail` permissions to be read/write by root only:

```
sudo chmod 711 /etc/mail
```

Comment: i called command `sudo chmod g-w /etc/mail/access.db`   but get again error: ```Mar 22 11:39:03 vectortrade sm-mta[18713]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): hash map "access": unsafe map file /etc/mail/access.db: Permission denied

```

Comment: @StefanHansch -I've edited my answer

Comment: thank you. but again same error, o my god!  ```Mar 22 11:52:50 vectortrade sm-mta[19331]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): hash map "access": unsafe map file /etc/mail/access.db: Permission denied
Mar 22 11:52:50 vectortrade sm-mta[19331]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=localhost.localdomain, arg2=127.0.0.1, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], reject=451 4.3.0 Temporary system failure. Please try again later.```

Comment: @StefanHansch I'm sorry that it didn't work :(  two last ideas.... 1) `sudo chmod 711 /etc/mail` and 2) restart sendmail

Comment: yes. with sudo chmod 711 /etc/mail work. Thank you.